nodejs polars .eq( <num> ) vs. .eq( <str> )
I'm playing with polars 0.11.0 (nodejs environment) and I don't fully understand this behavior:
let df2 : pl.DataFrame = pl.DataFrame({
  a: [1,9,3,9],
  b: ["one","one","three","four"],
  c: [1111,2222,3333,4444]
})

df2 = df2.filter( pl.col("a").eq( 9 ) )
logger.info("df2:", df2)

output:
┌─────┬──────┬────────┐
│ a   ┆ b    ┆ c      │
│ --- ┆ ---  ┆ ---    │
│ f64 ┆ str  ┆ f64    │
╞═════╪══════╪════════╡
│ 9.0 ┆ one  ┆ 2222.0 │
│ 9.0 ┆ four ┆ 4444.0 │
└─────┴──────┴────────┘

--- but ---
if i would like using str type column (b):
df2 = df2.filter( pl.col("b").eq( "one" ) )

output:
Error: not found: unable to find column "one"; valid columns: ["a", "b", "c"]
and have to use pd.lit():
df2 = df2.filter( pl.col("b").eq( pl.lit("one") ) )

┌─────┬─────┬────────┐
│ a   ┆ b   ┆ c      │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---    │
│ f64 ┆ str ┆ f64    │
╞═════╪═════╪════════╡
│ 1.0 ┆ one ┆ 1111.0 │
│ 9.0 ┆ one ┆ 2222.0 │
└─────┴─────┴────────┘

why need pd.lit() when i filter with str and why dont need when i filter with number?
please explain to me this behave. thank you!
if
df2 = df2.filter( pl.col("a").eq( 9 ) )

works
df2 = df2.filter( pl.col("b").eq( "one" ) )

why NOT?

When you use .eq(9) with Polars, it understands that 9 is a numeric literal. It directly uses this value to compare with the values in column a, but with string by default it expects a column name or an expression, with pl.lit() you correct the Polars default behaviour and make it treat "one" as a literal string value, not as a column name.
Simply if you need to filter with string you need to pl.lit like .eq( pl.lit("one")), if you need to filter with number, just pass the number like .eq( "one" ))

it's okay, but not to logical. if u see pandas:
df2 = d2[dataframe['a'] = 9]
.... and....
df2 = d2[dataframe['b'] = 'one']
it's clear

Super useful! Stuck me for hours...
